# Scala: Convert Recursive Function to Iterative Using Stack

Tags: scala, recursion, stack, iteration

The following code is the recursive code for splitting a list into two parts.

```
def split(lst:List[Int],lst1:List[Int],lst2:List[Int]): (List[Int],List[Int])=
lst match{
  case Nil => (lst1,lst2)
  case hd::Nil => (lst1,hd::lst2)
  case hd::tail => split(tail.init,lst1:::List(hd), tail.last::lst2)
}
```

I want to convert this recursive function to an iterative one using a stack.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: It doesn't need a stack, if when you say "iterative" you also allow vars. Please explain your actual problem more clearly

Comment: I did it without stacks in the test. But the professor marked me less and insisted I do it using stacks and that it can be done. And that is all that is mentioned in the question.

Comment: A queue I can understand. But a stack is LIFO which doesn't fit the problem at all. Ah, OK, I see what he means. Push the first element onto a stack. Push the second element on to another stack. If there's a third element, the one on the other stack is in the  wrong stack. Pop that and push it onto the first stack. Push the third (and fourth, if it exists) element on to the second stack, If there's  a fifth element element, the third needs to be moved from the second stack to the first. .... and so on. But a queue still works better...

Comment: Can you post the code for it? Apparently, I'm not really comfortable with stacks.

Comment: Busy (it's dinner time here). Might have a go later. But I really don't see how stacks are useful here. Queues, yes.

Comment: Yeah, it seemed weird to me too. But for some reason, the professor was very particular about it.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to solve the problem using stack

But It just brings a chaos and complexity in the code

In case you want just a simple solution, this is the answer

```
def split(lst: List[Int], lst1: List[Int], lst2: List[Int]): (List[Int], List[Int]) = 
(lst1 ::: lst.take(lst.length / 2), lst.drop(lst.length /2) ::: lst2)
```

Comment: Could you post the chaotic and complex code anyway? I'll try to make sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version using queues.

```
def iSplit(xs: List[Int]) = {
    val first = scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Int]()
    val second = scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Int]()

    xs.grouped(2).foreach { e =>
      e match {
        case List(a, b) =>
          second.enqueue(a, b)
          first.enqueue(second.dequeue)
        case List(a) =>
          second.enqueue(a)
      }
    }
    (first.toList, second.toList)
  }
```

We can change `first` to a stack, at the expense of a reverse

```
def iSplit(xs: List[Int]) = {
  val first = scala.collection.mutable.Stack[Int]()
  val second = scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Int]()

  xs.grouped(2).foreach { e =>
    e match {
      case List(a, b) =>
        second.enqueue(a, b)
        first.push(second.dequeue)
      case List(a) =>
        second.enqueue(a)
    }
  }
  (first.toList.reverse, second.toList)
}
```

but the problem for `second` is that we want to add things to one end and remove things from the other end. This isn't a stack, but a queue.

So I think you should tell your professor it works better with queues :)